# Parsing data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<blamatrixrix>
<name></name>
<columns number="2">
 <column id="title" num="0">Title</column>
 <column id="content" num="1">Content</column>
</columns>
<rows number="7"></rows>
<b>Description</b>
<b>Description text here</b>
<b>Some title 1</b>
<b>Some text blabla for Some title 1</b>
<b>Some title 2</b>
<b>Some text blabla for Some title 2</b>
<b>Some title 3</b>
<b>Some text blabla for Some title 3</b>
<b>Some title 4</b>
<b>Some text blabla for Some title 4</b>
<b>Some title 5</b>
<b>Some text blabla for Some title 5</b>
<b>Some title 6</b>
<b>Some text blabla for Some title 6</b>
</blamatrixrix>
```

I would need to parse that data into table so that every other **content** would go into a own  and every other in own .

Final would look like this:

```
<tr><td>Some title 1</td>  <td>Some title 2'</td> <td>Some title 3</td>  <td>Some title 4'</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some text 1</td><td>Some text 2</td><td>Some text 3</td><td>Some text 4</td></tr>
```

How should I start doing it? Thanks.

EDIT: I know the XML is not like it should but I cannot do nothing about it. I just need to parse it when its like that.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your XML is invalid:

```
<b>Description</c>
```

should be

```
<b>Description</b>
```

and

```
<bDescription text here</b>
```

should be

```
<b>Description text here</b>
```

Edit: you should also consider changing your XML structure to something more logical, like

```
<rows number="7">
    <row>
        <description>Description</description>
        <text>Description text here</text>
    </row>
    ...
</rows>
```

Edit #2: you can also just use jQuery to parse & traverse your XML, like so:

```
$(xml_string).children().each(function(c) {
    // do something
});
```

Or even better:

```
parseXMLValue($(xml_string).find('noniterablenode').text());
...
$(xml_string).find('iterablenode').each(function(e) {
    // do something with your iterable elements
});
```

etc, where `parseXMLValue()` would be your own function to use the value of a specific XML node.

Comment: Sorry, that just bad copy & paste from me. It is like that.

Comment: Yes I know its not very logical but unfortunately I cant do nothign to the xml. I just would need to parse it from that and I dont know where to start.

Comment: This seems to work :) Thank you for that.
$(xml_string).children().each(function(c) {
    // do something
});

But I dont know how to continue. Some sort of loop and then put it the table? If I conglose.log the c I get just numbers 1-16. Arrays?

Comment: You can just use `$(this)` inside that function to reference the current child in the iteration - generally you would either a) use those loops/xml parsing in general to manage a Javascript data structure (array/hash/etc) or whatever variables you need; you could then use that data to create the HTML (iteratively probably).  If you're sure your data will be consistent and valid, you could just start creating table elements while parsing the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Once the errors are fixed you could do something like the following:

```
$.ajax( 
  url: "path/to/file.xml", 
  type: "GET", 
  dataType:"xml", 
  success: function(xml){ 
    var cols = [];

    $(xml).find("col").each(function(){
      cols.push({
        id:$(this).attr('id'),
        text:$(this).text()
      });
    });

    $(xml).find("row").each(function(){
      var info = "<tr>";

      for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
        info += "<td>" + $(this).find(cols[i].id).text() + "</td>";
      }

      info += "</tr>";

      $("#table").append(info);
    });
  },
  error : function(){ //some code}
});
```

This would work with the following XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tableinfo>
  <columns>
    <col id="title">Title</column>
    <col id="content">Content</column>
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <title>test</title>
      <content>text content</content>
    </row>
    <row>
      <title>test2</title>
      <content>more text content</content>
    </row>
  </rows>
</tableinfo>
```